# Is the following variable replacement correct?

Tags: limits

Our teacher asked us to calculate $\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ln(x)}{x^n}$

Now I want to replace $x$ with $x^n$, while $n \in \Bbb N$ and tell me if it is correct to do the following:

$\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ln(x)}{x}$ = $\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ln(x^n)}{x^n}$

Since we have the same value inside of ln() and in the denominator, then it is the same limit.

Now we know that $\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ln(x)}{x}$ = $0$

So:

$\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ln(x^n)}{x^n}$ = $0$

$\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{nln(x)}{x^n}$ = $0$ (according to the logarithm rule).

$n \times \lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ln(x)}{x^n}$ = $0$ (since n is a constant).

Now we have either $n$ = $0$ or $\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ln(x)}{x^n}$ = $0$

But since $n \in \Bbb N$ then:

$\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ln(x)}{x^n}$ = $0$

Correct or not? Please if it's incorrect make sure to explain me where I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is formally correct, but it would have been easier to just say: since
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}=0
$$
then for $n\ge 2$
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}=0\cdot 0=0.
$$

Comment: I am aware and I had that idea too and it worked pretty fine but our professor specifically asked us to use variable replacement. But thanks anyway still.